# Decimal conversion fails when used in sub-namespace in Microsoft Bond

Tags: c#, bond

Following the example here: https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/tree/master/examples/cs/core/decimal

I am trying to use decimal in a struct that is not in the base namespace and get the exception "Expression of type 'System.Decimal' cannot be used for assignment to type 'System.ArraySegment`1[System.Byte]'".

If I keep all structs in the same namespace, everything works great. Is there some type of qualifying I have to do?

I've put together a small project and a couple unit tests to demonstrate: https://github.com/oculuss/BondDecimalExample

TestA has everything in the same namespace. TestB has a few sub-namespaces (and is what breaks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [BondTypeAliasConverter](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cs.html#converter) must be defined "in the *same assembly and namespace* as the class representing the Bond schema(s) in which the type alias is used or assembly/namespace of one of the types being converted." It cannot be defined in a parent namespace. The search algorithm isn't that smart. :-) Thus, in TestB, you need to put the BondTypeAliasConverter class in the C# namespace "BondExampleB.Global.SecondType.SecondTypeA" (or wherever you've mapped that to in C#).

There are an open design proposal to make this a bit easier. See [issue #594](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/issues/594) in the Bond GitHub project.

Until something comes from that, if you want to have the same converters for types in different namespaces, you'll need to do something like this:

```
namespace Util
{
    public static class BondTypeAliasConverter
    {
        public decimal Convert(ArraySegment<byte> blob, decimal unused) { ... }
        public ArraySegment<byte> Convert(decimal d, ArraySegment<byte> unused) { ... }
    }
}

namespace First
{
    public static class BondTypeAliasConverter
    {
        public decimal Convert(ArraySegment<byte> blob, decimal unused)
        {
            return Util.BondTypeAliasConverter.Convert(blob, unused);
        }

        ....
    }
}

namespace First.Second
{
    public static class BondTypeAliasConverter
    {
        public decimal Convert(ArraySegment<byte> blob, decimal unused)
        {
            return Util.BondTypeAliasConverter.Convert(blob, unused);
        }

        ....
    }
}
```